# V-if not working when property in it updated in async method TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

We have a case when one HTML element is hidden after async call is returned from the server and other HTML element is displayed:

```
<template>
   <div v-if="!showElementTwo">Element 1</div>
   <div v-if="showElementTwo">Element 2</div> 
</template>

<script lang="ts">

export default class extends Vue {
    showElementTwo = false;

    private someAsyncRequestToServer = async() => {
        // some async request to the server
        this.showElementTwo = true;   
    } 
}
</script>
```

`this.showElementTwo` is indeed changed to `true` but this does not re-render the elements (does not hide `element 1` and shows `element 2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this would be to perform update of `showElementTwo` in a separate method like this:

```
<script lang="ts">

export default class extends Vue {
    showElementTwo = false;

    show() {
      this.showElementTwo = true; 
    }

    private someAsyncRequestToServer = async() => {
        // some async request to the server
        this.show();
    } 
}
</script>
```

I guess that Vue cannot re-render elements based on a property updated in an async function (this might be only TS related issue)... Any additional thoughts, comments on this...?